# Python split list on delimiter

Tags: python

Seems to be a simple question but I tried a dozen of possibilities without result.
I just want to change ['55.00', ['CHF', '0.00']] into [['55.00'], ['CHF'], ['0.00']]
or:

```
var1 = "55.00"
var2 = "CHF"
var3 = "0.00"
```

As an example, I tried:

```
mik = ['55.00', ['CHF', '0.00']]
mik = [s.split(',') for s in ','.join(mik).split(',')]
```

Result:[['C'], ['H'], ['F'], [' '], ['0'], ['.'], ['0'], ['0']]

What could be the solution in my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpack your list. This answer assumes that you always have RHS of the format `[el, [el2, el3]]`

```
>>> var1, (var2, var3) = ['55.00', ['CHF', '0.00']]
>>> var1
'55.00'
>>> var2
'CHF'
>>> var3
'0.00'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mik = ['55.00', ['CHF', '0.00']]
new_lst = []

for item in mik:
    if type(item) == list:
        for x in item:
            new_lst.append(x)
        continue
    new_lst.append(item)
print(new_lst)
```

Simply you iterate over the list and if you found the item is itself a list you iterate over it's items and append them to your `new_lst` object and if it is not a list you just append it.

The output from the above code:

```
['55.00', 'CHF', '0.00']
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is basically to flatten your list if I understood correctly.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists) might be helpful.

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, Iterable) and not isinstance(el, (str, bytes)):
            yield from flatten(el)
        else:
            yield el

mik = flatten(['55.00', ['CHF', '0.00']])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have these 3 elements, you could do this:

```
mik = ['55.00', ['CHF', '0.00']]

mik[1:] = mik[1]

print(mik) # ['55.00', 'CHF', '0.00']
```

If there are multiple sublists and/or more than one level of nesting, you can use the same approach in a loop:

```
for i,_ in enumerate(mik):
    while isinstance(mik[i],list):
        mik[i:i+1] = mik[i]
```